# FFMPEG scale down image

Tags: ffmpeg

This is for you FFMPEG gurus!

I have video that I take a screenshot image of. This works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i sourceMovie.mp4 -ss 0 -vframes 1 destImage.jpg
```

But I was hoping to also scale down the image to 150 px wide, in one fell swoop. Apparently, I should add

```
scale=150:-1
```

But where and how do I insert that in the command?

I have tried everything; nothing works ...

Comment: The `-ss 0` in your command is superfluous as it means "skip the first 0 seconds".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scale is a VideoFilter, so you use "-vf":

```
ffmpeg -i sourceMovie.mp4 -ss 0 -vframes 1 -vf "scale=150:-1" destImage.jpg
```

Comment: Note: I think you need ffmpeg >= 0.10 (0.9?) in order to use -vf.

Comment: you will probably want to use "-2" instead of "-1" to let ffmpeg automatically adjust height to be divisible by 2.